# Are there any algorithms with a time complexity of O(sqrt(n) * log(n))?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

Googling "Are there any algorithms with a time complexity of O(sqrt(n) * log(n))?" doesn't bring up anything relevant.

Comment: This seems like a very random question. What's the purpose?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for some famous algorithm, then good luck searching that.

Else, you can create one such on your own:

```
for(int i = 1; i < sqrt(n); i +=1){
   for(int j = 1; j < n; j *= 2){
       // do some O(1) task.
   }
}
```

Comment: That's not an algorithm

Comment: @Amit - Just because a code is not published under some name doesn't mean that it is not an algorithm. I can say that it solves some definite purpose! Please refer to what an algorithm is!

Comment: [tag:algorithm]: "*An algorithm is a sequence of well-defined steps that defines an abstract solution to a problem*". Your empty loop does nothing and solves nothing.

Comment: So perform a calculation on `i` and `j` in the loop body, and state that it solves the problem of calculating that useless number that is a function of `n`.  There you have it: an algorithm.

Comment: @Amit - [`Algorithm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithm) ---> In mathematics and computer science, an algorithm is a self-contained step-by-step set of operations to be performed. Algorithms perform ***calculation***, data processing, and/or automated reasoning tasks.

Comment: Read ask the way through on the Wikipedia page. What calculation does your code accomplish? What are the steps of the algorithm? What is the output?

Comment: @Amit - (i) If i put a count of total number of times of iteration inside the inner loop, then it gives me the total number of times this inner code ran. Also, count++ is O(1). (ii) Steps consist of the two loops, and the count increment statement, (iii) output is the final result of count, which reflects how many times the inner loop body was executed successfully.

Comment: 1. What your comment describe is not what your answer contains. 2. Even if it did, it is at best a contrived excuse to create the nested loop, whereas you might as well directly calculate the result in O(1). 3. What's the purpose of your answer? Just post a comment expressing your opinion (that no known algorithm exists with this time complexity). If you're just posting to hunt for scores, you're not being helpful.

Comment: If I had to guess, this question is probably for a homework assignment, and the intent is to do something precisely along the lines of the answer given.  The student needs to show that they understand the meaning of the `O()` notation, and how it pertains to various algorithms, regardless of their purpose.

Comment: @Amit - I never write answers just for scoring. I never had those intentions, and never would have. I thought maybe OP is trying to figure out how a O(sqrt(n) * log(n)) complex algorithm looks like; so I just added this answer, even adding disclaimer at the very first line. Now, to answer your comments ---> 1. It is your comment which resulted in these many comments. OP never asked for clarifications yet. 2. Your thinking. 3. Anything which answers the question, unless extra information is provided by OP, is, ***in my view***, an attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @eddiem - if you have to guess, the question is low quality and unclear. Downvote it, close-vote it, post a comment... Don't "guess" an answer.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful - we'll have to agree to (broadly) disagree.

Comment: @Amit - Yes, let's happily move on and serve the purpose of being on SO. Good Luck.